# localStorage returns undefined when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm saving the array in `localStorage` but when I try to retrieve the data from it return undefined. Then I call upon the `retreiveData` function to display the data.

```
let LIST, id;

if (localStorage.getItem('todo')) {
    LIST = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
    id = LIST.length;
    retreiveData(LIST);
} else {
    LIST = [];
    id = 0;
}

function retreiveData(arr) {
    arr.forEach(el => {
        addToDo(el.toDo, el.id, el.done, el.trash);
    });
}

function addToDo(toDo, id, done, trash) {

    if (trash) { return; }

    const DONE = done ? check : unCheck;

    const newHTML = `
                <li class="item">
                ${toDo} <i class="${DONE} checked" data-task="complete" id="${id}"></i>
                <i class="ion-ios-trash-outline icon" data-task="delete" id="${id}"></i>
            </li> `;

    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHTML);
}

document.getElementById('listBtn').addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const toDo = input.value;

    if (toDo) {
        addToDo(toDo, id, false, false);
        LIST.push({
            name: toDo,
            id: id,
            done: false,
            trash: false

        });
    }
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(LIST));

    input.value = '';
    id++;

});



function markAsDone(element) {


    element.classList.toggle(check);
    element.classList.toggle(unCheck);

    LIST[element.id].done = LIST[element.id].done ? false : true;
}

function deleteToDo(element) {
    element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode)

    LIST[element.id].trash = true;

}


list.addEventListener('click', event => {

    const element = event.target;
    const elementID = element.id;

    if (element.dataset.task == 'delete') {
        deleteToDo(element);
    } else if (element.dataset.task == 'complete') {
        markAsDone(element);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(LIST));

});
```

Comment: The array is being saved in local-storage but somehow it doesnt return the data.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that shows how you're saving it.

Comment: Make sure to save values in localstorage as "text", so you need to do `JSON.stringify(value)`

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that you have stored it before getting assigned value so it is undefined, because even if you didn't stringify it it gets assigned as string as Array.toString() returns in and not undefined

Comment: Or maybe you are not getting the right property name that was saved in localStorage so that gives you undefined

Comment: The array LIST contains an object which is getting stored in local storage after pushed into the array.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. "array LIST contains an object which is getting stored in local storage", where are you doing the storage... can you `console.log(localStorage.getItem('todo'))`

Comment: I store the information in object and then push that object into array LIST. when I console log the array which contains the object is returned.

Comment: Can you please `console.log(localStorage.getItem('todo'))` and show the structure of the result as an image on your question. This will really help us understand the structure of the data we're dealing with.

Comment: "I store the information in object and then push that object into array LIST. when I console log the array which contains the object is returned." this makes sense. But we need to be sure that localStorage.getItem('todo') actually returns a value, that is why I am pleading for a `console.log()` on it.

Comment: [
  {
    "name": "Do shopping ",
    "id": 0,
    "done": false,
    "trash": false
  },
  {
    "name": "work on project",
    "id": 1,
    "done": false,
    "trash": false
  }
]

Comment: Could you please copy in the body of your question the localStorage assignation? What data are you storing at localStorage and how. Thank you.

Comment: localStorage.setItem('todo',JSON.Stringfy(LIST))

Answer (score 2):

Might it be that the `retrieveData()` function is `undefined` and not `localStorage.todos`?

Try something like this:

```
let list = [ { "name": "Do shopping ", "id": 0, "done": false, "trash": false }, { "name": "work on project", "id": 1, "done": false, "trash": false } ];

localStorage.todo = JSON.stringify(list);

let theData;
if (localStorage.todo) {
    theData = JSON.parse(localStorage.todo)
    console.log(theData);
} else {
    console.log('No todos');
}
```

> **OR**

It might be that you're trying to use `localStorage` on your local machine. For security reasons it won't work. What you might need to do is run it on a local server. You can do it by following these steps.

If you have PHP installed on your computer:

1. Open up your terminal/cmd
2. Navigate into the folder where your website files are
3. While in this folder, run the command `php -S localhost:3000` ← Notice the capital 'S'
4. Open up your browser and in the URL bar go to *localhost:3000*. Your website should be running there.

**or**

If you have Node.js installed on your computer:

1. Open up your terminal/cmd
2. Navigate into the folder where your website files are
3. While in this folder, run the command `npm init -y`
4. Run `npm install live-server -g` or `sudo npm install live-server -g` on a mac
5. Run `live-server` and it should automatically open up a new tab in the browser with your website open.

**or**

You can use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

**NOTE:** remember to have an index.html file in the root of your folder or else you might have some issues.

> **OR**

It could be the browser settings.

In Chrome, when you go to ***settings > site settings > cookies and site data***, there is an option that says ***Allow sites to save and read cookie data (recommended)***. If that is turned off then you won't be able to use localStorage either.

> **OR**

If none of the above fixes it, then you might want to wrap the function that saves to `localStorage` in a `try-catch` block and see if an error gets returned and take it from there:

```js
let list = [ { "name": "Do shopping ", "id": 0, "done": false, "trash": false }, { "name": "work on project", "id": 1, "done": false, "trash": false } ];

try {
  localStorage.todo = JSON.stringify(list);
} catch(error) {
  alert(error)
}
```

Comment: I didn't find any typos JSON.stringify(). The data is stored in local storage but its not returning

Comment: Oh I see @saedqaderi . In the comments it had a capital, but no matter. It might be the `retrieveData()` function hey. What if you do it without that function? Use the code up here to test in your app and see if it works. If it does then you can build on it.

Comment: I didn't see any difference it still returns undefined.

Comment: Aaah sherbet @saedqaderi , then it's not `localStorage`, but something else, because I tested this and it works. What I actually think it is, is that you're trying to use `localStorage` on your local machine. For security reasons it won't work. What you might need to do is run it on a local server. I'll update the answer to show you how to run it on a local server.

Comment: That's great mate. I'm waiting for the reply.

Comment: The program still returns undefined on the reload.

Comment: I tested the app on local server but it's still returning undefined when the page is being reloaded

Comment: That is so wierd @saedqaderi . What I think is might also be is the browser settings. In Chrome, when you go to **settings > site settings > cookies and site data** there is an option that says **Block third party cookies**. If that is turned on then you won't be able to use `localStorage` either. If it is off then I dont know what it could be, but what you could do is to wrap the `localStorage.todo = JSON.stringify(list)` in a `try-catch` block and see if an error pops up. I'll update the answer to show how to do that. Otherwise I dont know what it could be

Comment: I looked up the browser settings it’s turned off and I tried opening the app on different web browsers too. I’ll put the code inside try-catch block and will get back to you mate.

Comment: I found what I did wrong,I passed the wrong key name to  addToDo(el.toDo, el.id, el.done, el.trash) function when loading the list. The right key name is el.name not el.toDo.

Comment: Aaah awesome @hamid ! I'm glad you figured it out man! Thanks for giving some feedback 